# nesting an orientation break point in a min-width break point

Tags: css, sass, media-queries, orientation

i have nested an orientation break point in a min-width break point (SCSS), like this :

```
    @media only screen and (min-width : 481px) {
           @media only screen and (orientation: portrait) {
                // something
           }
           @media only screen and (orientation: landscape) {
                // something
           }

    }
```

my question : what's the width condition referring to ? the portrait or the landscape orientation ? or how does it work in general ?

Comment: check the CSS generated and you will understand

Comment: @TemaniAfif hello , sorry to bother you , but is saying that i'm a noob is against the rules ? just to be sure next time :D thanks for your answer aswell .

Comment: saying such thing is simply noises. This website is not a forum or a chat, so we should focus on content and everything related to programming and we should avoid things related to users. We don't need information about *you* or *me* but only about your issue ... so don't get suprised if they are deleted. It's not against you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The media query's width condition always refers to the current orientation's width. So when you are in portrait mode on a smartphone the width will be the shorter side, if you are in landscape mode the width condition will refer to the longer side.